# How to show default icons instead 'done' icon in angular mat-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-stepper

I am using angular 8.2.4 and horizontal mat-stepper. I have customized the icons in each step and I do not need to show the 'tick' icon (which corresponds to the done state) once each and every step is visited.  This is how it looks like now.
[image]

```
`<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true" class="register-stepper">
          <!--<ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
            <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
          </ng-template>-->
         <ng-template matStepperIcon="user">
                  <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
         </ng-template>
         <mat-step [completed]="true" state="user">
                  <ng-template class="form-control" matStepLabel>Basic</ng-template>
                  <h4 class="cgg-component-heading">Basic Information</h4>                  
                </mat-step>
        </mat-horizontal-stepper>`
```

I have already removed `the matStepperIcon="done"`.

How can I avoid this done state's icon displaying and keep the custom default icon as it is without showing the 'tick' icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add empty edit state It will override default behaviour

**Try this:**

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, it hides the 'done' icon, but do not show the default icons as well. Do you have any idea how to show default icons?

Comment: Does it override all your custom icon?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: SOrry I could not make my own code segment but I have tried the following link by adding your suggestion as: `<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
</ng-template>'  Here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x9ujf1?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html

Comment: Have you tried to add you can add default icon inside <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit"> </ng-template>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207836/discussion-between-smash-and-chellappan-).

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more clarity, on what you mean by default icon. From your image above I'm assuming you want the "account_circle" icon on all of your steps. In that case, the below code would work.

```
<!-- START - Material Stepper  -->
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <!-- Icon overrides. -->
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="active">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="number">
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
<!-- END - Material Stepper  -->
```

Just replace the state with whichever icon you want. Unless you explicitly replace the state, your icon would not be used by material stepper.